# Qu'est-ce que « le la valeur » dans ces phrases ?

Tags: grammaire, articles

J'ai trouvé cette phrase quand j'ai cherché des informations sur le *ne expletif*, mais je ne comprends pas pourquoi on utilise les deux articles: **le** et **la**.

> Il renforce le la valeur du verbe "redoute".

J'ai pensé qu'il était une faute de frappe mais j'ai trouvé une autre phrase avec **le la valeur** dans le *Capital*:

> D'abord  Aristote  exprime  clairement  que  la  forme  argent  de  la marchandise  n'est  que  l'aspect  développé  de  la  forme  valeur  simple, c’est-à-dire  de  l'expression  **le  la  valeur**  d'une  marchandise  dans  une  autre marchandise  quelconque, car il  dit…

Je pense que c'est archaïque, mais je ne sais pas pourquoi l'auteur de l'article sur le ne expletif a utilisé cette construction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dans la première phrase, je pense que c'est un mot en trop. La phrase naturelle est

> Il renforce la valeur du verbe "redoute".

Il faudrait voir plus de contexte pour être sûr.

Dans la deuxième phrase, *le* est clairement une faute de frappe ou une erreur de numérisation, le mot devrait être *de*.

> … l'expression **de** la valeur d'une marchandise dans une autre marchandise quelconque

La succession de deux articles définis n'est pas possible. Pour avoir la succession de mots « le la », il faut que *la* soit la note de musique (donc un nom commun).

Comment: http://sosgrammaire.voila.net/neexplet.html ici j'ai trouvé la premier phrase.

Comment: @NicholasJ. Je confirme, le *le* est en trop, tout simplement.

Comment: Merci beaucoup!!

Answer (score 0):

Il s'agit de coquilles, Marx a écrit:

> ..., c'est à dire l'expression **de** la valeur d'une marchandise ...

En dehors de l'exemple de Gilles (la = note de musique), on peut trouver *le* suivi de *la* quand le deuxième mot fait partie d'un nom propre, par exemple, [Le La Fontaine russe](http://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/008614741), ou [Le La Fontaine en action](http://www.eyrolles.com/Loisirs/Livre/le-la-fontaine-en-action-ou-la-moralite-de-chaque-fable-de-la-fontaine-developpee-et-prouvee-par-un-trait-historique-ou-biographique-ouvrage-specialement-destine-a-l-instruction-de-la-jeunesse-par-c-hygin-furcy-edition-de-1875-8264749200066) ou quand *la* n'est pas utilisé comme un article : Le la qui précède le le est erroné ;-).

Comment: Et dans le premier exemple?

Comment: Un « le » en trop.